# mysql char, varchar and decimal byte size

Tags: mysql, varchar

I was reading the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html) on the byte size for different data types, but was a little confused when it came to char, varchar and decimal.

Can somebody help explain the bytes for these three data types, and also answer how many bytes for the following:

```
char(7)
varchar(9)
decimal(15,2)
decimal(11,6)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**CHAR(N)** is probably the most confusing because a char is not a fixed byte size across character sets. Furthermore, different row formats handle this problem differently. Tersely, if you're using ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT, ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED then CHAR(N) reverse a minimum of N bytes in order to achieve updates in place without fragmentation. If more bytes are required as the result of a different character encoding than it will use more as necessary, trying to use as few as possible, and NO MORE than the maximum character byte length * N is used. If you're using ROW_FORMAT=REDUNDANT, than CHAR(N) always uses the maximum character byte length * N.

**VARCHAR(N) and VARBINARY(N)** sets a maximum character length per column of N. Below N, MySQL uses the number of bytes required given the string and character encoding used. MySQL then uses one additional byte to record the length of the string if the string is below 256 bytes. If the length of the string is greater than 255 bytes than it uses 2 bytes to record the length of the string. VAR columns are storage efficient but for string columns with frequent UPDATES, one can trade storage for performance by using a fixed length column such as BINARY.

**The DECIMAL** description is pretty self explanatory:
"Values for DECIMAL (and NUMERIC) columns are represented using a binary format that packs nine decimal (base 10) digits into four bytes. Storage for the integer and fractional parts of each value are determined separately. Each multiple of nine digits requires four bytes, and the “leftover” digits require some fraction of four bytes. The storage required for excess digits is given by the following table"

Comment: So for Char with ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT, ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED, what you are saying is that CHAR(N) will allocate at least N bytes e.g. char(15) will allocate minimum of 15 bytes? And for VARCHAR(N), it would be N+1 e.g., varchar(15) would allocate 16 bytes? And varchar(256) would allocate 258 bytes?

Comment: You could say CHAR(N) would allocate a minimum of N bytes and VARCHAR(N) allocates a **maximum of N chars (which will be >= 1 byte each) + 2 bytes**